# Jquery - Show Image ALT tag in seperate div on hover

Tags: jquery, image, alt, captions

I have a gallery of images that i have set up and when a user hovers over one I wan't it to show the title in a separate div. Ive tried the below code but to no avail. I'm not great at jquery so could someone please correct me?

Div's

galleryimages - Where the thumbnails (to be hovered) are kept

gallerydescription - Where the Title tag from the image is to be displayed.

I would like it also on mouse out that it would clear the description DIV.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("img.galleryimages").hover(
           function () {
          ("#gallerydescription").html( $(this).attr("alt") );
           }, 
           function () {
              ("#gallerydescription").html("");
           }
        );
     });
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
("#gallerydescription").html( $(this).attr("alt") );
```

should be:

```
$("#gallerydescription").html( $(this).attr("alt") );
```

Note the '$' at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Doh, Thanks heaps!

one dollar sign hey :(

Comment: @Dylan B: It's always the littlest things that are hardest to find.